# 'tuple' object has no attribute 'all'

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I am trying to develop a django web portal that contains a form which needs to be populated from two models. I am basically doing this..

```
class PositionForm(forms.ModelForm):
    position = forms.ModelChoiceField(PraveshEnums.POSITIONS)
    status = forms.ModelChoiceField(PraveshEnums.STATUS_OPTIONS)
    domain = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Domain.objects.all())
    subdomain = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Subdomain.objects.all())
```

However when I try loading that view, it gives

> 'tuple' object has no attribute 'all'

error.

I have been trying several sources online but haven't been able to find any reason why it is happening. Appreciate if anyone can help me in this. Thanks.

Comment: Your syntax is main problem I think...Maybe the error in unrelated to your piece of code you put here

Comment: CAn you post your Domain and submdomain models ?

Comment: try changing `forms.ModelChoiceField` to `forms.ChoiceField` for `position` and `status`. `ModelChoiceField` expects a queryset. hence the issue.

Comment: I’m not sure you are allowed to use `.objects.all()` before all models are loaded

Comment: @karthikr thanks it worked. If there was a way to accept your answer from comments, I would have done it. Thanks anyways again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[ModelChoiceField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/forms/fields/#modelchoicefield) has single required argument: queryset. You are not passing a queryset for position and status fields.

Comment: Perfect! Worked like charm! Wasted 4 hours on this.. Thanks!